# Need to know about some some tools and skills

Tags: animation, resource-recommendations, video

I don't really know if it's the right place to ask this, but I want to know what should I learn (software, skills...) to start making videos like these ones:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aO9mOAKXvJs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqA42M4RtxE
of course I'm talking about what goes into the "making" and not the content side

Answer (score 1):

Software wise, I would create the individual illustrations in Adobe Illustrator, then animate them using Adobe After Effects.